# Random sequence iteration in O(1) memory?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, complexity-theory, permutation

Say you want to iterate over a sequence [0 to n] in a random order, visiting every element exactly once. Is there any way to do this in *O*(1) memory, i.e. without creating an [1..n] sequence with `std::iota` and running it through `std::random_shuffle`?

Some kind of iterator spitting out the sequence in a random order would be optimal.

A requirement is that it should be possible to get another random order by picking another seed.

Comment: Is there an upper bound to the value of `n`?

Comment: A uniformly distributed random number in the range [0, n] will do the job in theory. I am not sure however how to write *proper* code for this task using C++11 random facility.

Comment: @AraK Would a uniformly distributed PRNG emit each element exactly once?

Comment: I don't think you can do what you asked. But you can minimize the memory footprint by creating a vector of pointer to you elements and use `std::random_shuffle` on that.

Comment: Note that even if you can't do it in O(1) memory, you can get down to `n` bits, if you can accept and ignore repetitions (may take much longer, and may even loop forever if your PRNG is limited enough). That will take you a long way, you only need a 32th of the space to store each number explicitly (assuming 32 bit integers).

Comment: @Fiktik in the particular problem I'm working on yes, but n is still quite large > 10e9

Comment: Just a thought. This all sounds like you want a hash function.

Comment: @ahenderson Not really. I want to iterate over the contents of a vector. But I want to do it in a different order every time.

Comment: Yeah, the "different order every time" seems to rule out both pre-configured RNGs and destructive mutation.

Comment: That "different order every time" requirement is quite a critical one, and should be added to the original question. Were that not the case, the trite answer would be "yes, of course!" as iterating the sequence in index order is a _possible_ random ordering.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's covered by the common understanding of the term "in a random order". On the same basis that https://xkcd.com/221/ is commonly understood to be humorous, granted that it also makes a fair point that the word "random" is commonly abused or under-specified. Similarly, are we going to say that the updated question only calls for 2 distinct random orders, the seed being of type `bool`? ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In theory, if you built a random number generator whose period was exactly *n*, and covered all values in 0..n, then running through this once would give you what you like.

Of course, this may not be a general solution, at least if you are looking for something dynamic, since you would have to pre-create the PRNG and how you do this depends on n.

Comment: My knowledge of pseudorandom number generators is quite limited. Is it possible to build/parameterize a random number generator for an arbitrary period of n? Would it be possible to generate several different generators with the same period?

Comment: Also, the PRNG itself would need to have `O(1)` internal state -- there are some pretty obvious ways to build such a PRNG that violate that ;-)

Comment: You can create a full-period linear congruential RNG for many values of n, and these are known to have O(1) internal state.  I do not know of any general method to compute such generators given the value of n.  What I do know is that for some values of n, an O(1) memory PRNG _can_ be built and also that for some values of n multiple sequences can be generated.  I do not know how to construct these on the fly for arbitrary n (or even if a general algorithm exists to do this -- in the case of LCRNGs there are IFF-restrictions on what gives you a full period).

Comment: Thank you for these insightful comments. I conclude that the "PRNG with period n" solution is unfeasible in the general case. Especially if one would also like to be able to generate an arbitrary number of different PRNGs with period n to get different permutations.

Comment: @4ZM Could you explain your choice to accept this answer, although you state that the "... solution is unfeasible in the general case"?

Comment: @sehe Sure. It seems that the answer to my question: "Is there any way to do this in O(1) memory?" is: in theory maybe (using some not yet invented parameterizable PRNG with period n), but in practice no.

Comment: An LFSR based on a primitive polynomial will do exactly what you described if n can be 2**x or 2**x - 1.

Comment: Which is not the general case.

Comment: @sehe I wouldn't mind if the answer was unaccepted, but in fairness the phrase "A requirement is that it should be possible to get another random order by picking another seed." was added _after_ the answer was given and I did state it wasn't general solution, just a one-off.

Answer (score 7):

If you could mutate the sequence in-place, you could simply repeatedly draw a random number from 0-N, and then erase the element you visited, or swap it to the end, or such schemes.

Comment: This might be the best practical solution. It would reduce the memory footprint from 2n to n. I guess it would make sense to store the sequence in a deque to allow chunks of heap to be released as they are no longer required.

Comment: +1 This is how i've done this in the past. given a reasonable range size for output, use any seeded RNG % #items-remaining, remote that item as the output value and repeat.

Answer (score 1):

As with most algorithmic problems, there is a time-space trade-off; this can be solved in O(1) space if you're happy to use O(n^2) time to generate all the permutations. Aside from a couple of temporary variables, the only storage this requires is the random number seed itself (or, in this case, the PRNG object), since that is sufficient to regenerate the sequence of pseudo-random numbers.

Note that you have to give this function the same PRNG on every call, and you can't use it for any other purpose.

```
#include <random>

template<typename PRNG, typename INT>
INT random_permutation_element(INT k, INT n, PRNG prng) {
  typedef std::uniform_int_distribution<INT> dis;
  INT i = 0;
  for (; i < k; ++i) dis(0, i)(prng);
  INT result = dis(0, i)(prng);
  for (++i; i < n; ++i) if (dis(0, i)(prng) <= result) ++result;
  return result;
}
```

Here's a quick and dirty harness. `./test 1000 3` generates 1000 complete permutations of length three; `./test 10 1000000 0 5` generates the first five elements of each of 10 permutations of length one million.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::random_device rd;
  std::mt19937 seed_gen(rd());
  int count = std::stoi(argv[1]);
  int size = std::stoi(argv[2]);
  int seglow = 0;
  int seglim = size;
  if (argc > 3) seglow = std::stoi(argv[3]);
  if (argc > 4) seglim = std::stoi(argv[4]);
  while (count-- > 0) {
    std::mt19937 prng(seed_gen());
    for (int i = seglow; i < seglim; ++i)
      std::cout << random_permutation_element(i, size, prng)
                << (i < seglim - 1 ? ' ' : '\n');
  }
  return 0;
}
```

There is a faster way to do this if you're unlikely to finish any given permutation, but this way of writing it looks nicer, and is maybe easier to understand. (The other way is to generate the numbers in the opposite order, which means you can stop after you've generated k of them but you have to do it twice, first to get result and then to adjust it.)

Comment: -1 for not wrapping it in a class when you need invariants preserved between calls, and for all-caps template arguments.

Comment: @DeadMG: OK. Glad you're reading my two-year-old answers. There's a good argument for wrapping that in a class rather than providing the state argument on every call, but the stateless functional style also has its adherents and my history tends more in the functional direction. If you want to edit the template arguments to a style you prefer, please do so with my blessing.

Answer (score 0):

No there is not, think about it, somewhere the program has to remember the places it has visited. If there is an iterator that can randomly access them all, the iterators internals would have to keep track of this somehow and you would still be using the memory.

Comment: Or, alternatively, you could simply remove the places you've visited.

Comment: This is thoughtless, invalid position. There are plenty of obvious O(n)-space iteration schemes that obey the invariant of never visiting the same element twice. The fact that none I can think of are psuedorandom is not evidence that none exist.

Answer (score 0):

Well... think about that for a second. How would you 'know' which elements had been visited before?

Short answer: you can't. (**Edit** Well, not unless you count stateless Pseudo-random generators, but as you have stated yourself in the command, that doesn't seem feasible for the general case)

Depending on the actual sequence, it might, however, be feasible to **'mark' elements as *visited* _in-place_** thus technically requiring O(n) storage, but **no *extra* storage** for the algorithm

Example:

```
const int VISITED_BIT = 0x8000; // arbitrary example

bool extract(int i) { return (i & ~VISITED_BIT); }    
bool visited(int i) { return (i & VISITED_BIT); }    
bool markvisited(int& i) { i |= VISITED_BIT); }

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {2,3,4,5,6};

    int remain = v.size();
    while (remain>0)
    {
        size_t idx = rand(); // or something
        if (visited(v[idx]))
            continue;

        std::cout << "processing item #" << idx << ": " << extract(v[idx]) << "\n";
        markvisited(v[idx]);
        remain--;
    }
}
```

Comment: I’m not convinced. The history/state *could* be encoded in the current random index. After all, that’s how a LCG works (see Ray’s answer). It’s difficult, but not fundamentally unfeasible, and defeats your claim.

Comment: It's not impossible, just really hard. You'd have to have an algorithm that generates random numbers from a range exactly once. This algorithm probably exists for any n (though I didn't check), the problem is just that it won't be the same for n and n+1.

Comment: How interesting that both the comments seem to be discussing the solution I chose to _not describe_. Huh

Comment: @sehe Well I commented *before* you added the caveat about using the state of the PRNG, and before you’d added a detailed description of the next best solution.

Comment: @KonradRudolph you're quite right. My code sample dates 50s after your comment. That explains that :)

Comment: @Konrad: Only for some sizes of N. For example, if you used a single bit to determine whether each item was visited, that limits you to 64 items- even for a large integer. Here, you're using n/32 memory- which is an improvement, but still O(n).

Comment: @DeadMG While an interesting observation, this isn’t really all that relevant because **every** algorithm suffers this limitation once implemented in a real-world computer. Want a O(1) space complexity Fibonacci function? Well you can’t because the result has O(n) digits.

Comment: @Konrad: Actually, it uses O(log(n)) bits. This is definitely better than O(n) bits. In addition, it only requires storage for the result- if the result is considered to be constant-sized, then so is the algorithm when viewed in this frame. However, yours definitely is not.

Comment: @DeadMG It uses O(log(n)) bits if n is the *result*, not the input (as in, the n-th Fibonacci number). Then it needs O(n) bits. The LCG case is exactly equivalent since both are just ℕ → ℕ functions (and the hypothetical permutation algorithm only uses the LCG’s state, no additional memory).

Answer (score 0):

I've just built a structure for this sort of thing - I generate a Heap structure (min or max, doesn't matter).  But for the comparison, instead of using a key value, I use a random number.  Items inserted into the heap are thus placed in random order.  Then you can either return the array that forms the heap's base structure (which will be randomly ordered), or you can pop the elements off one by one, and get them back in random order.  If this type of your container is used as your primary storage (rather than having an array separate from the heap), there is no additional memory complexity, since it's just an array anyhow.  Time complexity is O(log N) for insertion, O(log N) for popping the top element.  Shuffling is as simple as popping and reinserting each element, O(N log N).

I even built a fancy Enumerator (it's C#, but you could do the same with a C++ Iterator) that auto-shuffles after you've iterated through to the end.  That means that every time you can iterate through the list (without popping) multiple times and get a different order every time, at the cost of an O(N log N) shuffle after each full iteration.  (Think like a deck of cards.  After every card has gone to the discard pile, you reshuffle the deck so as to not get them in the same order next time around.)

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but I needed such a pseudo random ordering, and the answers were not very useful to me.

Consider two operations:

1. You can xor "i" with some random mask: j=i xor k1. It makes nice "mess" out of the order, but can go out of bounds. The good thing about it is that it is replacing pairs of elements, so you can just not do it if you'll end up out of bounds.
2. You can multiply i by some constant that is coprime with n (gcd(n,k2) = 1) modulo n: j=i*k2 mod n.

One can combine these to make a nice fast pseudo-random "mess" of the ordering:

```
int getIndex(i) {
 if (i^k1 < n) i = i^k1;
 i = (i*k2) % n;
 if (i^k3 < n) i = i^k3;
 i = (i*k4) % n;
 return i;
}
```

Where k2 and k4 are precomputed to be co-prime with n, and k1 and k3 should be lower than n.